# extraction for array in json

Tags: sql, json, duckdb

```sql
CREATE TABLE example (j JSON);

INSERT INTO example VALUES
('{
    "family": "anatidae",
    "species": [
        {"name": "duck", "animal": true},
        {"name": "goose", "animal": true},
        {"name": "rock", "animal": false}
    ]
}'
);
```

How can I find if `duck` is one of the species?

It looks like I need to apply an extraction function to an array like:

```sql
SELECT 'duck' IN j -> '$.species' ->> 'name' AS is_duck_here FROM example
```

Comment: It looks like I'm licking something like `[*]` - `j -> '$.species[*].name'`

Comment: yes speoes is an array so you need to add which element you mean or like in your comment all of them

Comment: I need all the elements :) to check if `duck` is in any of them

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `JSON_CONTAINS`

```
select * from example where 
json_contains(json_extract(j,'$.species[*].name'),json_array('duck'));
```

[**dbFiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6TQnoLCEnLX5gPNRY4ctMX/1)

Test result:
[image]

Comment: Beautiful solution, thanks! Unfortunately, it does not work in DuckDB that I use. But it seems like it works just fine in MySQL & PgSQL. I'll accept the solution once it implemented in DuckDB :)

Answer (score 0):

To extract values of array you need to unpack/`UNNEST` the values to separate rows and group/`GROUP BY` them back in a form that is required for the operation / `IN` / `list_contains`.

```sql
SELECT FIRST(j) AS j,
       list_contains(LIST(L), 'duck') AS is_duck_here
FROM (
    SELECT j,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS id,
           UNNEST(from_json(j->'species', '[\"json\"]'))->>'name' AS L
    FROM example
) GROUP BY id
```

I have not find any easier way of doing this so far.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell duckdb does not currently support [*] in a json path; it seems to use a json library implementation from sqlite which does not support this functionality.

I created my own macro:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MACRO json_array_extract_text(jsdata, jspath) AS (
    WITH jsp AS (
        SELECT x
        FROM (SELECT STR_SPLIT(jspath, '[*]') AS x)
    ), arraylen AS (
        SELECT
            json_array_length(jsdata, x[1]) AS len
        FROM jsp AS x
    ), jindex AS (
        SELECT RANGE(CAST(x.len AS BIGINT)) as ix
            FROM arraylen as x
    ), jindex_xpand AS (
        SELECT UNNEST(j.ix) AS index
        FROM jindex AS j 
    ), paths AS (
        SELECT x[1] || '[' || ix.index || ']' || x[2] AS path
        FROM jindex_xpand AS ix
        CROSS JOIN jsp AS x
        ORDER BY ix.index
    )

    SELECT ARRAY_AGG(json_extract_string(jsdata, p.path)) AS array
    FROM paths as p
);
```

It uses the `json_array_length` function to determine how many indices to build and then builds the paths by replacing [*] which each index.
Would appreciate any clues in how to simplify this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE example (j JSON);

INSERT INTO example VALUES
('{
    "family": "anatidae",
    "species": [
        {"name": "duck", "animal": true},
        {"name": "goose", "animal": true},
        {"name": "rock", "animal": false}
    ]
}'
);

SELECT list_contains(json_array_extract_text(e.j, '$.species[*].name'), 'duck')
FROM example AS e;
```

output

```
    list_contains(json_array_extract_text(e.j, '$.species[*].name'), 'duck')
0   True
```